# Smartwatch with round screen and running regular Android 4.4.2

Tags: android

I have a smartwatch with round display and it is running Android 4.4.2. My app is working fine on smartwatch with square display running Android 4.2.2 but the UI gets cropped in round display. It seems all the APIs for round screens are for Android wear. I would like to adjust the UI of my app to fit on round screens but do not want to create a separate Android Wear project for it.

Is there a way to use the Android wear APIs while developing app for devices running regular Android?

Thanks in advance.